# Functional component problems React

Tags: reactjs

I transformed a class component into a functional component but it looks like it does not work in a way it suppose to work and I can not find what is wrong. When I create a new object there is no `name` for the object and when I try to mark the object as a `complete` it removes all created objects at ones. I created a `codesandbox` here. Unfortunately, I am not too much familiar with functional component. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my `codesandbox` sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sid-09myu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have updated the code, please check link https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-n8lgx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Assign `name` works, but mark as `complete` still does not work. Though thanks for the first part. Could you please check the second part?

Comment: Actually your `onClick` function operating on `originalTodos` but you to handle `todos`

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-n8lgx?file=/src/App.js:608-615

Comment: Try this one, https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-n8lgx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Hemakumar It is very close to what it should be but there is still error because the task will not be complete unless I write something into `input` field. But it is very close. Could you please check it one more time.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code, please check the URL https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-n8lgx?file=/src/App.js

```
  const onComp = id => {
    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      if (todos[i].id === id) {
        let t = { ...todos[i] };
        t.complete = !t.complete;
        todos[i] = t;
      }
    }
    setTodos([...todos]); // Here todos reference need to be changed
  };
```

And also

```
  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        id: generateNewId(),
        name: newTodoName,
        complete: false
      }
    ]);
    setNewTodoName("");
  };
```

While using hooks we need to be careful about state variable updates. While manipulating arrays and objects use the spread operator to create new references which invokes child components and re-render current component.

Answer (score 1):

Your Todos:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
        { id: uuid(), name: "Task 1", complete: true },
        { id: uuid(), name: "Task 2", complete: false }
    ]);
```

onAddHandler:

```
const addTodo = () =>
setTodos([...todos, { id: uuid(), name: "New Task", complete: false }]);
```

onSetCompleteHandler:

```
const setCompleteHandler = id =>
setTodos(
  todos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
      return {
        ...todo,
        complete: todo.complete ? 0 : 1
      };
    }
    return todo;
  })
);
```

I have created your new todos. Check out this link
[Todos App](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-platform-bzp4k?file=/src/App.js)